# How to display xml returned from server in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, rest, datagridview

**Project architecture:** 
WindowsForm - WCF Service - SQLite database

**Aim:**
I want to return a requested cars' details from the database, through the server (using REST) and onto a DataGridView on the client side.

**Problem:**
At present I'm returning an XML string to a text box which includes the details I want...

```
<GetCarByIdResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetCarByIdResult>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Car2" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="Car2"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="CarID" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="Make" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="Year" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType>    </xs:element></xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<DocumentElement xmlns=""><Car2 diffgr:id="Car21" msdata:rowOrder="0">    <CarID>2</CarID>
<Make>Toyota</Make><Model>Corolla</Model><Year>2007</Year></Car2>    </DocumentElement></diffgr:diffgram></GetCarByIdResult></GetCarByIdResponse>
```

but I can't find a way to put this information into the DataGridView. I've tried `XMLReader`, `XDocument`, `dgCar.DataBind();` without luck. I'm very new to this so any pointers greatly appreciated. Find my code below. Thanks in advance.

**Server side code:**

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse , UriTemplate = "/GetCarById/{value}")]
 DataTable GetCarById(string value);

//////////////////////////////////////

  public DataTable GetCarById(string value)
  {
      string connectionPath = @"Data Source=C:\SQLite\Car2.sqlite;Version=3;";
      SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath);
      {
          connection.Open();

          string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Car2 where CarID =" + value;
          SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

          cmd.Connection = connection;
          cmd.CommandText = SQL;
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
          DataTable dt = new DataTable("Car2");
          adapter.Fill(dt);

          return dt;

          connection.Close();
```

**Client side code:**

```
private void btnGetCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:56328/Service1.svc/GetCarById/" + txtShowCarById.Text).Result;
    HttpContent stream = wcfResponse.Content;
    var data = stream.ReadAsStringAsync();

    txtRest.Text = data.Result;
}
```

Comment: The response of the service seems to be in json which is weird since you have defined a ResponseFormat Xml. Are the infos up to date?

Comment: Sorry Jérémie, I edited the response there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ReadXml method` of a `datatable` or `dataset` then bind the grid to it.

```
public DataTable ReadXml(string xmlString)
{
    // Create the DataTable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
         //Create the columns with coresponding names
         dt.Columns.Add("CarId", typeOf(int));
         dt.Columns.Add("Make" typeOf(string));
         dt.Columns.Add("Model" typeOf(string));
         dt.Columns.Add("Year" typeOf(int));

         //Using ReadXml to populate the table
         dt.ReadXml(xmlString);

         //Return the table
         return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw some exception
    }
}
```

You can find more documentation about this in the links below:

[DataTable.ReadXml Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DataSet.ReadXml Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Tiberiu, will try that now

Comment: To make the answer better, you should provide more content rather than just links. Keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: You're right. I've edited it, hope it's better now. Thanks for the feedback.